# How comments are handled?

Tags: support, comments

I was looking again at [Installing and importing Google Earth Engine Python API](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/433296) which was posted yesterday. I had some feedback with the OP trying to find the problem and the OP finally solved the issue. Today I checked again the question and all comments were gone. Since I could probably have the same issue, I'm interested on how to detect the issue.

What are the criteria to delete comments? In this case, I didn't delete mine, so somebody else did it (for both I suppose, OP and I)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work) it says:

> **When should comments be deleted?**
>
> [Comments are temporary "Post-It" notes left on a question or answer.
> You should not expect them to be around forever.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) Once a
> clarification has been made, an edit added to the post to include new
> information, or the issue in the comment is otherwise resolved, it can
> be deleted. Additionally, any comment that violates the comment
> guidelines listed above or the Code of Conduct is subject to deletion.
>
> In reality, on most sites, many since-obsolete or guideline-violating
> comments don't end up being deleted due to the high volume of comments
> posted, but this does not mean that they can't or shouldn't be deleted
> in the future.

The comments deleted from the question you asked about were:

[image]

When I reviewed those comments, the question and the answer, I came to a conclusion that the asker was satisfied that their question had been (self-)answered, and so I deleted all comments on it then, rather than relying on the comments being deleted at another time in the future.

The aim for all Q&As on Stack Exchange sites is that their "wiki-fication" will lead to only a clear question and its clear answer(s) remaining in the permanent record.

If you ever see a comment deleted that you want to use to improve an existing Q&A, or to start a new Q&A, just flag it for a moderator to undelete it temporarily, so that you can copy its content before it is again deleted.